# PHP or MySql error; Possible to display an "error page" in browser?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, .htaccess

My classifieds website uses mainly **PHP** and **MySql**.

On error, (for example if a variable isn't found), I would like to have an error-page to show, is this possible? And I mean for every error to point to the same error-page.

I am thinking about `htaccess`, but maybe there are other ways also?

Same with MySql, how is it done there?

Thanks

Comment: Since you have a classifieds website, I would assume you mean, for example, `www.mysite.com/cars.php?id=5` where if the car with id=5 is not present you get redirected to a "item not found" type page? You're not talking about PHP's errors/warnings/notices right?

Comment: I you redirect the user to a generic error-page, you can't show specific error-messages anymore. Showing a generic error-page isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I use error exceptions all the time (http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)...

So, at the beginning of my code, I have the following:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Then, I wrap everyting in a giant try{}catch{} block.  So I can "catch" the error higher, but if I don't, it displays an error message to the client:

```
ob_start();
try {
    //Do Stuff Here, include files, etc
} catch (Exception $e) {
    ob_end_clean();
    //Log the error here, including backtraces so you can debug later
    //Either render the error page here, or redirect to a generic error page
}
```

The beauty is that it'll catch ANY kind of error.  So in my DB class, I simply throw a DatabaseException (which extends Exception).  So I can try/catch for that when I make my call if I want to fail gracefully, or I can let it be handled by the top try{}catch block.

Answer (score 2):

You can do stuff with the PHP error handling methods that will probably be what you are looking for.  There is a decent tutorial [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6113787.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a custom error handler to do the redirect. First, enable output buffering, otherwise it is not possible to call the required `header()` function.

```
ob_start();

// This function will be our custom error handler
function redirect_on_error(int $errno , string $errstr) {
    // Ignore the error, just redirect the user to an error page
    ob_end_clean(); // Erase any output we might have had up to this point
    header('Location: error.html'); // Or wherever you want to redirect to
    exit;
}

set_error_handler('redirect_on_error'); // Set the error handler

// Your code goes here

ob_end_flush(); // End of the page, flush the output buffer
```